# Text auto-scrolling in JavaFX TextArea

Tags: javafx, textarea

Hello guys i'm making a calculator using Javafx and want the text in the TextArea to auto scroll left when it become larger than the teaxtarea size

## Edited

Question Answered below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using this methods after every setText

```
object_Name.selectPositionCaret(lbl.getLength());
object_Name.deselect();
```